# Oracle Parallel Query behaviour with IDE tools as SQL Developer or Toad

Tags: oracle, oracle-rac, parallel-query

For a while I've trying to get the time to write this question and explain the issue as best as I can, so forgive me in advance for the long text.

My environment:

- Oracle Database 12.2 running on Red Hat 7 ( R.A.C 2 nodes ) - 16CPU and 64GB RAM per node.
- Parallel Force Local is set to TRUE to force that parallel server processes can only execute on the same node where the SQL statement was started.

We have a very big database that contains a lot of schemas which serve several applications. Most of the  applications are in reality batch processing engines in PL/SQL that treat hundredths of millions of records, so most of the big tables have been configured with PARALLEL DEGREE DEFAULT for performance reasons. Tables are partitioned and with advanced compression.

Besides some reporting BI tools for exploitation purposes, many end users have access with SQL Developer to the System ( only in read mode ) for QA checks. I never liked, but sometimes you have to accept how things are.

To control a bit the things, I designed a specific logon trigger that covers not only auditing features but also some aspects of the incoming sessions:

- An End User accessing with SQL Developer might open only 2 sessions.
- An End User accessing with SQL Developer runs an execute immediate ALTER SESSION DISABLE PARALLEL QUERY. Unfortunately, I know that some users are activating it by themselves. The ALTER SESSION ENABLE/DISABLE PARALLEL QUERY is inherited by the CREATE SESSION privilege or CONNECT role, so I can't do anything about this.
- An End User accessing with SQL Developer is assigned to a specific profile with restrictions in terms of CPU , DISK READS, etc.

The logon triggers allows or not the access based on a set of additional rules , but for the purpose of the question they don't matter.

Let's see how queries running on SQL Developer behave against tables with PARALLEL enable:

**Scenario**

I have a table containing 8 billion records split by different partitions. A user log in with sql developer and runs this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE PARTITION ( MY_PARTITION ) ;

183.940.801 rows
```

As the table has no indexes, the CBO runs a TABLE FULL SCAN in PARALLEL using as many slaves as it considers. It takes 6 seconds to complete. So far, nothing wrong.

Meanwhile I am monitoring the session ( you can see all sessions active when the query is running )

```
  INSTANCE     SID USERNAME             PROGRAM                                            SQL_ID               STATUS
---------- ------- -------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------- --------
         2       6 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00N)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     128 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P004)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     140 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P007)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     256 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00O)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     284 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00D)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     388 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00C)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     400 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00P)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     510 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00E)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     621 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00F)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     641 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00Q)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     739 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P008)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     771 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P005)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     888 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00R)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     893 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00G)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2     996 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00H)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1010 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00S)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1015 FDM_ADM_GRID         SQL Developer                                      dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1109 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00T)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1116 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00I)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1230 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00J)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1254 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00U)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1352 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P009)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1376 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P001)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1383 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P006)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1477 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00V)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1488 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P000)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1506 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00K)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1604 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P002)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1617 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00L)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1620 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00A)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1740 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P003)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1743 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00M)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
         2    1851 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00B)       dtf8d89xg7muq        ACTIVE
```

Once the query finishes

```
SQL> r
  1* select inst_id as instance , sid, username, program, sql_id, status from gv$session where username = 'FDM_ADM_GRID'

  INSTANCE     SID USERNAME             PROGRAM                                            SQL_ID               STATUS
---------- ------- -------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------- --------
         2    1015 FDM_ADM_GRID         SQL Developer                                                           INACTIVE
```

So far so good. Now let's run this other query in SQL Developer

```
SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE partition ( MY_PARTITION ) fetch first 1000 rows only;
```

The query retrieves the first 1000 rows almost instantly. But let's see the difference in the database

When it was running

```
SQL> r
  1* select inst_id as instance , sid, username, program, sql_id, status from gv$session where username = 'FDM_ADM_GRID'

  INSTANCE     SID USERNAME             PROGRAM                                            SQL_ID               STATUS
---------- ------- -------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------- --------
         2       6 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00N)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     128 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P007)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     140 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P004)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     256 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00D)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     284 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00O)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     388 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00P)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     400 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00C)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     510 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00E)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     621 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00F)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     641 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00Q)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     739 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P008)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     771 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P005)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     888 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00G)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     893 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00R)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2     996 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00H)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1010 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00S)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1015 FDM_ADM_GRID         SQL Developer                                                           ACTIVE
         2    1109 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00I)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1116 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00T)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1230 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00J)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1254 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00U)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1352 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P006)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1376 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P009)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1383 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P001)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1477 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P000)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1488 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00V)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1506 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00K)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1604 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P002)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1617 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00A)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1620 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00L)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1740 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P003)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1743 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00M)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
         2    1851 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00B)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
```

As soon as the query completes, I check back again, however now all the slaves are still there and in status ACTIVE. I would have though that as soon as the QC is finished and marked as inactive, Oracle would have closed all slave processes. But it doesn't

```
  `INSTANCE     SID USERNAME             PROGRAM`                                            SQL_ID               STATUS
---------- ------- -------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------- --------
     2       6 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00N)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     128 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P007)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     140 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P004)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     256 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00D)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     284 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00O)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     388 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00P)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     400 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00C)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     510 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00E)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     621 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00F)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     641 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00Q)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     739 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P008)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     771 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P005)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     888 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00G)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     893 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00R)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2     996 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00H)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1010 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00S)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1015 FDM_ADM_GRID         SQL Developer                                                           INACTIVE
     2    1109 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00I)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1116 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00T)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1230 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00J)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1254 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00U)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1352 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P006)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1376 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P009)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1383 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P001)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1477 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P000)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1488 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00V)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1506 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00K)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1604 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P002)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1617 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00A)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1620 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00L)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1740 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P003)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1743 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00M)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
     2    1851 FDM_ADM_GRID         oracle@scglvdoraci0010.scger.pre.corp (P00B)       9jyvj64ag15mv        ACTIVE
```

As long as the session remains open, the QC will remain inactive and the slaves ACTIVE, thereby although they are not doing anything, they still count as parallel servers. Either the session is closed or the user runs another another query for me to notice changes in parallel use. But there won't be any if the user goes to take a coffee, or goes to launch or is doing something else.
With more than 100 users concurrently working, you might imagine the headache. I had to design some workarounds:

- I had to create a new control inside the trigger to identify the inactive time of QC vs slaves in status ACTIVE, in order to identify how many sessions the user has already opened.
- I had to create a cleaning process to disconnect sessions in this status after a window time of 1 hour
- I can't use limit sessions in Profiles because they don't difference between QC or SLAVES.
- No matter how many things I configured, sometimes I ran out of parallel processes and if a batch process is executed in business hours ( which happens a lot ) I faced sometimes lack of parallel availability for those important processes due the number of slaves occupied by the inactive sessions.

My questions are the following:

- Why the slaves remain in status ACTIVE when the QC has already finished ? Should not the slaves be terminated as soon as the QC has delivered the results ?
- Why this behaviour does not happen neither in SQLPLUS nor in Java Pool solutions ( as SAP Business Objects ) when they run very similar queries ?
- Is there a way to disable parallel capabilities from the end users, no matter they try to activate them by ENABLE PARALLEL QUERY or through HINTS ?

I apologise for the long question, but I did not want to leave anything.
I would really appreciate any insight about this.

Thank you all.

Comment: Have you looked at Resource Manager? It has some parallel execution limits that you can set for certain users by putting them in different consumer groups. I have had problems with tables with degree DEFAULT. A fixed number like 8 seems to work better for me. You have 2 nodes and 16 cores each so I would think DEFAULT=32 which seems excessive but your post shows degree 16 queries so I don't know why that is. I thought DEFAULT=nodes*cores.

Comment: I tried to buiild a test case for Resource Manager, but I had so many issues that the time I was consuming was not worth it. I though about fixing the degree, but it was creating more problems than solving the issues that default was producing. Besides I have so many times in the batch that the whole server is occupied in one single query

Comment: Probably your DEFAULT degree is 16 because you set PFL to True so it only sees it as 1 node. Degree 16 is reasonable. It is a bummer that the SQL Developer sessions are holding on to the PQ slaves. Yuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries are not truly completing. Although your query only fetches the first 1000 rows, SQL Developer is only fetching the first 50 rows of those 1000 rows. The IDE won't close the cursor until you scroll to the last row. Once you retrieve all the data, those parallel processes disappear. Make sure you see "All Rows Fetched: 1000 in X seconds", instead of ""Fetched 50 rows in Y seconds". (I wish SQL Developer would make it more visually obvious that there are additional rows waiting.) You won't see this problem in SQL*Plus because SQL*Plus always grabs all the rows.

When only the first N rows are fetched, those parallel processes are "ACTIVE" but are not doing anything. You *should* be able to ignore those sessions since they are not using any significant resources.

If you're worried just about the number of parallel sessions, you might want to adjust your expectations. I used to be in the same situation as you - constantly telling users that their (incomplete) queries were hogging all the parallel sessions. Eventually, I discovered that it was only a problem because I had created an artificially scarce resource. Oracle parallel processes are usually lightweight, and databases can support way more parallel processes than most people think they can.

What are your parameter values for PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS, PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU, and CPU_COUNT? Look at the default value for [PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS.html#GUID-B6CE9EA3-B846-4AA7-B668-FD3BEE433A24). Per the manual, the default number is: `PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS = PARALLEL_THREADS_PER_CPU * CPU_COUNT * concurrent_parallel_users * 5`.

Most DBAs see a maximum number of parallel threads in the hundreds, panic, and then decrease that number. And then we start yelling at developers for using an unimportant resource that was artificially limited. Instead, we should crank the number back up to the default, and just ignore random parallel sessions. If a user isn't exceeding IO or CPU limits, it shouldn't matter how many parallel threads they use.

(With the possible exception of preventing *massive* parallel query session usage. Put your users in a different profile, and set their SESSIONS_PER_USER to a few dozen. Do NOT limit it to just 1 or 2. IDEs need extra sessions for multiple tabs, background processes that grab metadata, and debug sessions. If you set the limit to 2, your developers will not be able to use an IDE properly.)

---

**EDIT (response to comments)**

I'm not sure if you can read much into the status of the [query coordinator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm#i1006328). The QC does several things, but ideally it will be idle most of the time while the parallel sessions handle most of the work.

With the producer/consumer model, half of the parallel sessions may be receiving data but not really doing anything - like they're just memory structures in some operations. Parallel sessions may switch between active and inactive, as not all steps will need as many sessions. But we wouldn't want Oracle to close sessions in the middle, as they may be needed later and we wouldn't want to waste time opening and closing sessions.

There are dozens of factors that affect the degree of parallelism, but as far as I know increasing PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS will not affect the number of parallel servers requested for a single statement. (But if the statement was already asking for more servers than the max, increasing the parameter may affect the number of sessions allocated).

It might feel like SQL statements are just randomly grabbing all the parallel sessions, but ultimately DOP calculations almost always follow deterministic rules. It's just that the rules are so complicated, it's difficult to tell how it works. For example, one common point of confusion is that whenever a query adds sorting or grouping, the number of parallel sessions is doubled.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I will check tomorrow whether those slaves are closed if I ran your query. I set parallel_max_servers according to Oracle documentation following their rules. Thankfully my users are end users, so no developers, but I just calculate the limit of sessions in the logon trigger. I  used the profile for limiting cpu and disk reads though ;)

Comment: I verified that normal queries as select * from table or any of that kind that request a dataset greater than the handled by SQL developer produces the issue. I also verified that for 50 rows the slaves are closed. I will accept your answer, as it solves many of the issues I raised on my question.

Comment: What I don't really get is why Oracle is not releasing the slaves as soon as the QC changes to inactive status, although now I understand that the query is still there because SQL Developer only fetch the first 50 rows, they should be released under my point of view. If the end user fetch more rows, then the QC should be able to get new slaves to complete the job. I guess there might be an internal issue that prevents this behaviour, because if not I honestly don't get it. At the end I had to create a complex job to find all and disconnect them.

Comment: I'm going to change `parallel_max_servers` to a value greater than the recommended one. If I do it, do you think that queries with multiple joins can get even more slaves ? I realised that queries in SQL developer sometimes when multiple tables are involved they can get up to 128 slaves.